# BufferedReader and Scanner in different classes

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I am reading several files using (BufferedReader and Scanner several time in my code).etc The issue what i have is that my code exists in one class the (main class ).

when i try to split it into different classes (to get the main clas with only few lines of code) i get different kind of errors.

E.g i tried

```
public class ReadFile {
    public static BufferedReader in (InputStream in){
    //The same code here 
    //URL book = new......
    return new BufferedReader(inStreamReader(in));
}

 }
```

Comment: Please look into creating a [mcve] for us. We really do not like being pointed for off-site links to access your source code; and you dropping all the source code here is also not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to split it into different classes (to get the main class with only few lines of code) I get different kind of errors.

Refactoring classes (simply) to reduce the per-class line count is probably a bad idea.  Refactoring a ~100 line class to reduce the per-class line count is (frankly) counter productive.

A ~100 line class is small enough that it should not present readability issues based on its length.  A ~100 line method is possibly too long, but there is no need to put the methods into separate classes.  If anything, splitting this into multiple *classes* would make it harder to read the code.  (Based on my experience ...)

If you are going to do any refactoring on that code, I would recommend that you split the `main` method into smaller methods.  However, the key to successful refactoring is identifying the *best place* to split things.

For instance, I would make the code from `// Open the file` to `reader.close()` a separate method, that takes a `File` as a parameter, and returns a `HashSet` populated by reading the file.

The ideal is to produce clean methods with small APIs and minimal coupling via shared variables.  And ideal method should also do one task, or a group of related task, rather than part of a task or a grab-bag of (largely) independent tasks.  A method like this is more likely to be easy to read and understand, independently of other methods.  That should be the primary goal of refactoring: making the code as a whole easier to understand.